# How can I identify a user correctly during a refresh_token grant?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, refresh-token

I have a central 'hub' containing the data for multiple organisations, each of which contain multiple users. Organisations and users are grouped together, along with 'client_credentials', under a 'Project'.
The user can authenticate using the 'password' grant type, and they obtain access & refresh token, as per the OAuth2 spec. Both are JWT.

The issue I have is correctly attributing the refresh token withe the relevant user in the 'correct' way so that I can issue a JWT access_token with the correct content.

When requesting the original tokens, I pass and validate both the client credentials and the user's username/password. Two identical (other than expiry time) tokens are generated containing the user_id and other bits. One for access, one for refresh.

So when validating the refresh token, I see (unless my understanding is wrong) a few ways of making this happen:

- On the initial request, store the refresh_token against the user's database record, and do a lookup based on the association with the client credentials as well as this stored token. OR:
- Generate the new access token from the unpacked refresh_token, just with a new expiry date - meaning I don't need to actually persist these things.

In some ways, the first approach seems ok, apart from my reluctance to perform database queries using any type of password/token, as typically I'd never index these fields.
And in other ways, the second approach seems ok as it doesn't actually require me to persist sensitive tokens unless I explicitly want to mark it for revocation - but it does somewhat require that the access_token and refresh_token are kept pretty much the same.

Any steer on which is the 'correct' approach, or does anyone have any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Password Grant type, you are generating/receiving two tokens: Access Token and Refresh Token. These tokens should be stored securely either in a memory table in your application or in a database. If you are using an autoscaling or fault-tolerant design, you need to use a database.

Once you have the tokens, you create an `opaque` random number (usually 128-bit, sometimes 64-bit), let's call it `AUTH_ID`. The tokens plus expiration are indexed by this `AUTH_ID`. You store the `AUTH_ID` in the client browser's session or return with the tokens. If there is a design already in place, then you will need to create a method to search the database to match the tokens passed to you. If the user does not actually require tokens, give them the `AUTH_ID` instead.

When the client makes a request to you, extract the `AUTH_ID` from the client session and lookup the tokens. If a token will soon expire, refresh it and store the new token. Then continue with the client's request.

The contents of a Refresh Token is implementation-specific. This means that if you want to rely upon information about a Refresh Token (or an Access Token) you must store that information alongside the token. Some tokens are Signed-JWT, some are Opaque.

Comment: Ok, so basically storing the tokens is the typical approach to this problem as opposed to just sending them out and relying on your ability to decode them for the required information?

Comment: You should store tokens, usually in a database. Unless your design requires the client to have tokens, sending tokens (specifically the Refresh Token) to the client is a bad idea. You may or may not be able to decode the tokens as this is implementation-specific and you cannot rely upon this unless a vendor's specification says otherwise. An Identity Provider can use opaque tokens, Signed-JWT or anything they feel like. The exception is Identity Tokens.